# ENCRYPTION :"DES" with "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1"

Tags: encryption, des

Could I use "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1" algorithm with "DES" encryption.

Comment: try it and see what happens.

Comment: You could, but it's certainly not secure.

Comment: @RenatoLochetti it seems like you are pretty much over smart, it a question as obvious so i wish you rather focus on solution if you could...

Comment: Guys i asked such because I am not able to use this Random number generating algorithm with "AES" but with "DES" I can't...I just want to know why?

Comment: hehehe some body down voting me ... but i can't figure it out why ?

Comment: You didn't post your code. This question can't be answered, because it doesn't contain enough information about what you're doing. You certainly can generate DES keys any way you like, be it a KDF or PRNG. It's also unclear why you want to use DES. Its 56 bit key means that it's very weak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are probably using `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1` to generate a key with 128 bits or more, which won't work with `DES` since it uses a 56 bit key.

I don't know what language you are trying to generate a key in, but there should be a parameter to specify key length.  make sure its specified to output a 56-bit key.

the 56 bit key length for DES is also why you shouldn't use DES.  your key will be brute forcable in under a day.  Use AES.

Comment: I could use see following `SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory
    .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    
  KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), SALT,
    ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH);
    
  SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
  
SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "DES");

  ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
  
  ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret)`

Comment: make sure `KEY_LENGTH` is equal to 56

Comment: that's the confusion i am having right now see when i put `KEY_LENGTH` to 56 it gives me error `Invalid key length` don't know why? **according to 'DES' specs 'KEY_LENGTH' has to be of 56 length** and for `KEY_LENGTH=64;` it's working fine. _also i am afraid of posting new question.each time i post any question here you guys are down voting me. HEHEHEHHAHA ;)_

Comment: @TheVOYOU Some implementations of DES expect a 64 bit key, and ignore 8 of them. Dumb historical artifact. DES is pre-historic crypto that shouldn't be used anymore.